# Is this a correct way to count territory in Go (by Chinese rules)?

Tags: go, counting

I am not sure if I misunderstood the territory counting rules of Go or simply I ran into a software bug. One of the Go programs I use counts territories like this. Would you explain me please why B6, C8, F7 were not counted for black?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Clearly - a - bug

Comment: Is it taking those as *komi* points perhaps? Strange that it it is implicit instead of explicit though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those points should count.  There must be a bug in the program.